# Mypy errors on enum auto() value

Tags: python, enums, mypy

I have this class for auto-name enums.

```
class AutoNameEnum(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return name
```

This is taken straight from the [Python documentation on enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values).

Usage is like this

```
class Priority(AutoNameEnum):
    LOW = auto()
    HIGH = auto()

priority = Priority.LOW
```

This all works fine and mypy understands everything here. But when I try to put `AutoNameEnum` into a separate package I get an error. Specifically, this

```
from utilities import AutoNameEnum

class Priority(AutoNameEnum):
    LOW = auto()
    HIGH = auto()

priority = Priority.LOW
```

results in

> Incompatible default for argument "priority" (default has type "auto", argument has type "Priority")

What does this mypy error mean, and why does it only happen when I import the class from a different package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually had nothing to do with `auto` or `Enum`. I simply had to indicate that my package was typed by adding a file called `py.typed` to the root of the package. Without that, mypy did not scan the package for types.